# After "break all" in Visual Studio 2010, some threads' call stacks are mostly missing in my C++ program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stack-trace

The latest revision of my cross-platform C++ application (using Juce) has what's probably a deadlock or conceivably an unbounded loop in Windows but not Mac and unfortunately we don't have a Windows developer at this time so it's up to me.

I can run the program under Visual Studio 2010 with problems, and then when I hit the "loss of liveness" :-D I use the "Break all" command, which seems to suspend all my threads.  Fine and good, and most of the stacks are perfectly reasonable.  Unfortunately, several of the threads, including the two I suspect of being in deadlock, don't have usable call stacks.

I perfectly well understand that the "tops" of my stacks won't be there, because I don't have debugging info for e.g. ntdll.dll.  But I just seem to get a tiny bit from the *middle* of the stack.

I'm including one of the bad stacks and one of the good stacks for your perusal.  You can see that the good stack traces all the way back to the calling function of the thread, but the bad stack only has a single valid frame.

That frame is legitimate, but I don't know why I can't see the other frames, and it's making my work very difficult.

Any ideas would be appreciated - hope your day has been more productive than mine!  :-D

**EDIT:**  Sorry, thought I was very clear above when I pointed out that I knew that the Microsoft symbols were missing, but don't care.  The issue is that the stack trace is missing all the frames *within my code* where I am sure I have debugging symbols.

I actually got past my deadlock, so this isn't a problem right now, but it makes the effect even more puzzling, as I now know that I hadn't e.g. screwed up the call stack somehow.

Now, I do have some more information for "the next guy" - it's that I was calling a function on a top-level Window from a thread was that NOT the windows thread.  (This is a cross-platform app, and on the Mac it doesn't care what thread you call these from.)  This was what was causing the "deadlock" (actually, I don't think it wasn't really a deadlock, but some other "loss of liveness"), and I wonder if it was this issue that also made Visual Studio 2010 refuse to display the stack correctly.

**-- bad stack --**

```
ntdll.dll!7c90e514()
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]
user32.dll!7e4299ff()
```

> SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::Win32ComponentPeer::setPosition(int x, int y)  Line 513  C++
>       SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!008005f9()

**EDIT:**  Yes, I saw the fact that "no symbols were loaded for ntdll.dll" but that's not the issue:  the issue is that there's only ONE frame in the stack.  See the next stack for an example of a "good stack" from a different thread in the same program.

**-- good stack --**

```
ntdll.dll!7c90e514()
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]
ntdll.dll!7c90df5a()
kernel32.dll!7c8025db()
kernel32.dll!7c802542()
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::WaitableEvent::wait(const int timeOutMillisecs)  Line 103 + 0x10 bytes   C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::Thread::wait(const int timeOutMilliseconds)  Line 304    C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!rec::util::thread::Looper<int (__cdecl*)(rec::slow::Instance *),rec::slow::Instance *>::run()  Line 24 C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::Thread::threadEntryPoint()  Line 145 C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::juce_threadEntryPoint(void * userData)  Line 156 C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!juce::threadEntryProc(void * userData)  Line 126 + 0x9 bytes   C++
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!_callthreadstartex()  Line 314 + 0xf bytes C
SlowGold 8 (debug build).exe!_threadstartex(void * ptd)  Line 297   C
```

> kernel32.dll!7c80b729()

**EDIT:**  you can see here that even though I don't have the full stack, I have plenty of frames from my own code - you can see where we enter from the top of the thread, and where we call into the Microsoft DLLs.

Comment: It tells you right here what your problem is: `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]`.  So load ntdll.dll symbols from the symbol server, as slugonamission suggests.

Comment: I would like more details about what you saw with the "calling a function on a top-level Window from a thread was that NOT the windows thread". I am having a similar problem with Visual Studio 2005 in which sometimes the application hangs as it is shutting down.  If I do a Break All using the debugger there is a pause then an error dialog indicating a possible deadlock.  Looking at the threads many are at address 7c90e514 though not all with the Call Stack window function call addresses seem to be missing.  In my case it appears that there is something about COM and Release() that is not right

Answer (score 2):

It just sounds like you have missing symbols (as not all are given), however, Microsoft distribute most, of not all symbols, on their symbol server.

Note: I have never had to do this. In any case, have a look at Microsoft's symbol server to figure out how to do this here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503.

Comment: The page you linked isn't appropriate for Visual Studio.  Here's a better one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx

Comment: It's interesting to have the MS symbols - but I don't really care, and that wasn't my issue, see the edits above!  But thanks for getting me those symbols, it will at least prevent a lot of warnings and such...

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! As I said, I've never had to do this, but I know roughly what had to be done.

Comment: @HansPassant the link you provided is broken. but this one works - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need debug symbols for system .dlls to properly walk the stack. Even if you happen to get seemingly correct entries in the callstack, you still can have erroneous callstacks if the stack itself has stale data (e.g., old return pointers).

Since you are using VS 2010, you should be able to right click on any system .dll in the callstack and load the symbols directly from the Microsoft Symbol Server. You can also go into Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols to have the debugger do this automatically.

You should always use the system .dll symbols when you can.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1)  "Clean" the solution, then build and run in debug mode again (making sure to choose *Start Debugging* (F5) not "Start Without Debugging" (which is CTRL+F5)

2)  Well, those are Windows API functions - are you *sure* for bad stack that you need to debug at that level?  The "bad stack" goes into user32.dll, which is the GUI side of Windows.  I don't think you *need* to debug those stacks, but I can't be sure.

Comment: 1) I tried the clean, no change!  Always a good idea tho... 2) I never did care about the Windows API functions in the stack trace;  see my edits above...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late for a response but I had a similar issue that took me a while to track down and like the OP I couldn't find anything on SO or Google in general that fixed the problem. I'm answering here because the scenario in this question is very similar to mine so Google is likely to find the question for others.

With my issue we had one PC with the complete stack trace and one with an incomplete stack trace. The way I found the solution was to use the Visual Studio Modules window (**Debug menu | Windows | Modules**). This window tells you which modules are loaded and importantly which modules have symbols loaded. In my case both machines had symbols loaded for the DLL with the incomplete stack, but critically one machine had a runtime DLL without the symbols loaded where as the other did. For me it was the Visual C++ runtime file Msvr110.dll. Once the correct symbol file was tracked down for this DLL, the full stack trace was reported correctly.

In the Module Window you can right click on a module file with a Symbol status of *Cannot find or open the PDB file* and select **Symbol Load Information...** to see the cause of the symbol load failure, including all search paths attempted and if there was a symbol mismatch that would occur if the symbols do not match the version of the DLL you have loaded in memory. From here it's just a matter of getting the PDB file from the working PC and making sure it's deployed correctly.

I hope this saves others some time.